# Having problems with the mouseup event

Tags: javascript

Hello I am working on two functions swapFE() and swapEF(). The purpose of these two functions is to exchange the French phrases with the English phrases which I've already done.

When I press the mouse button down on each phrase the English translation appears which is what i want it to do.

The problem is when I release the mouse button the French phrase should reappear and it doesn't happen. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I would appreciate it if someone can help me. Thanks for your time and for your help.

```
function swapFE(e){
var phrase = e.srcElement;
var parent = phrase.parentNode;
var idnum = parent.childNodes[0];
var phrasenum = parseInt(idnum.innerHTML)-1;
phrase.innerText = english[phrasenum];
phrase.className ='english';

}


function swapEF(e){
var phrase = e.srcElement;
var parent = phrase.parentNode;
var idnum = parent.childNodes[0];
var phrasenum = parseInt(idnum.innerHTML)-1;
phrase.innerText = french[phrasenum];
phrase.className ='french';
}
```

Comment: You may well want to show the code you are using to bind the events as well.  When you release the mouse button, are you still over that element?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your html it's difficult to determine if your issue is (1) your javascript method (I'm assuming swapEF) isn't working correctly or (2) the assignment of your event handler is not working or both. Make sure you are using the correct event functions ( "[mousedown](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html)" and "[mouseup](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html)") and try to test your functions manually in a javascript debugger like firebug or the Chrome javascript console. That will help you pinpoint the issue and fix your problem, but without the html and the assignment of your event handler it is difficult to post a solution.